# How can I use Mockito to verify that any/none of a set of overloaded methods is called?

Tags: java, mockito

I have a `BarService` with multiple related overloaded `update` methods on it, like so:

```
BarService#update(Bar bar);
BarService#update(Bar bar, boolean checkX);
BarService#update(Bar bar, boolean checkX, boolean checkY);
```

I want to be sure that *none* of them are called in a particular test. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
@Test
public test doFoo_shouldNotUpdateBar() {
    setUpTest();
    doFoo();
    verify(barService, never()).update(any(Bar.class)));
    verify(barService, never()).update(any(Bar.class), anyBoolean()));
    verify(barService, never()).update(any(Bar.class), anyBoolean(), anyBoolean()));
    ...
}
```

I can clean this up a bit by moving all the `verify` calls into a helper method to check all the overloaded versions:

```
@Test
public test doFoo_shouldNotUpdateBar() {
    setUpTest();
    doFoo();
    verifyBarServiceNeverUpdates(any(Bar.class));
}
```

But is there a way to get Mockito to do what I want here? Basically, to check that an overloaded method is / is not called without regard to its arguments?

Comment: I've proposed this as a [new feature](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2350)  for mockito.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely do not to *manually* put up "verification specs" that *list* methods that are not used (on such a scale as implied here). What happens when you add a new method tomorrow? Then you would have to turn to all your tests and add the new method there. That is *not* a sustainable pattern!

Instead:

- verify these calls you intend to happen
- and then call [`verifyNoMorInteractions()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoMoreInteractions(java.lang.Object...)) on your mock object to ensure that well, no other method was called

Comment: This is a viable option, but unfortunately it pollutes my test with a bunch of stuff I don't want. Let's say `barService` does `X` and `Y` before calling `update`. Now I have to explicitly `verify(barService).doX` and `verify(barService).doY` before I can call `verifyNoMoreInteractions(barService)`. But I don't actually know or care about `doX` and `doY` in this test, so they're just distractions.

Answer (score 3):

If Bar is a Mock and you want absolutely NO interactions, you can use Mockito's [verifyZeroInteractions](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyZeroInteractions(java.lang.Object...)) method as follows;

```
Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(bar);
```

**Update:**
As mentioned in the comments by @DanielPop, `verifyZeroInteractions` was marked as deprecated and it's no longer available. You should move to use [verifyNoInteractions](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.8.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verifyNoInteractions(java.lang.Object...)) instead.

Comment: This would work but unfortunately I can't count on there being zero interactions; I just want to make sure no `update` method is ever called.

Comment: the method was renamed to `verifyNoInteractions`